# using criteria to list phone numbers outside a specific area code

Tags: ms-access

I am using queries for MS Access, and I need to list people who live **Outside 614 area**.  No matter how I write it in the criteria, I still get phone numbers that have a 614 area code.

So how do I write the criteria so I only get phone numbers Outside 614

Please Help Me!!!

p.s. the phone numbers are formatted as (###) ###-#### in case that makes a difference.

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far so that we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With phone numbers stored in my sample table in *(###) ###-####* format ...

```sql
id phone_number
-- --------------
 1 (614) 123-4567
 2 (999) 876-5432
```

... this query uses `Not Like` to exclude those which begin with *(614)*.

```sql
SELECT f.id, f.phone_number
FROM tblFoo AS f
WHERE f.phone_number Not Like "(614)*";

id phone_number
-- --------------
 2 (999) 876-5432
```

That was the result from running the query within an Access session.  If you will be running your query from outside an Access session and using ADO to connect to the Access db, you need to use `%` instead of `*` as the wild card character.

```sql
WHERE f.phone_number Not Like "(614)%";
```

If a similar query doesn't work correctly with your data, make sure the phone number values are stored with the format you expect.  It's possible to have a display format which presents the data differently than it is actually stored.